# dfa implementation in python for readling web addresses

Tags: python, dfa, defaultdict

recently I made a python implementation of a fairly simple DFA that's intended to check web addresses, and now I have a program that compiles and runs successfully! My only issue now is bad output. Here is my current code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dfa = {'initial': defaultdict(lambda: 'invalid', w='w'), 'w': defaultdict(lambda: 'invalid', w='ww'), 'ww': defaultdict(lambda: 'invalid', w='www'), 'www': defaultdict(lambda: 'invalid', [('.','www.')]), 'www.': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*', [('.','invalid')]), 'www.*': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*', [('.','www.*.')]), 'www.*.': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*', [('c','www.*.c')]),'www.*.c': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*.c', [('o','www.*.co')]), 'www.*.c': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*.c', [('a','www.*.ca')]), 'www.*.co': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*.co', [('m','www.*.com')])}
cases=["www.commercial.com", "www.co.com", "www.x.com", "njit.ca", "www.stanford.com", "www.com.com", "ww.com.com", "co.ca", "www.ca.co.ca", "www.com", "www.ca", "www.cat.com", "wwwb.co.ca", "www..com", "www.abcd.co", "www.company.co.ca", "company.co.ca", "www.co.co.ca", "www.com.co.ca", "www.co.ca"]


s = input("Would you like to input a string? y/n ")
if(s == 'n'):
    exit
elif(s == 'y'):
    def accepts(transitions, initial, accept, s):
        state = initial
        for char in s:
            state = transitions[state][char]
        if(state == 'invalid'):
            return 1
    return state in accept
for case in cases:
    if(accepts(dfa,'initial',['.com','.co','ca'],case)==1):
        print(case + " is an invalid web address!")
    else:
        print(case + " is a valid web address!")
```

Running the program for the test case, 'www.hi.com' exits and returns "invalid url". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Running this will execute fine until it reaches this part of the DFA:

```
 'www.': defaultdict(lambda: 'www.*', [('.','invalid')])
```

Note I had to use a tuple to handle for a dot as a key, since it isn't accepted. It is here to test for this case:     "www.."

Comment: move dfa and accepts definition out of the outer if construct, they do not depend on the input. Also weren't you supposed to implement a trap state, not terminate early on invalid? If so, you are missing a transition table entry for the invalid state. `'www': defaultdict(lambda: 'invalid', w='www.')` is wrong: After 'www' we expect a '.' to be leading to the next state 'www.'

Comment: Needed the tuple for that state, forgot. Regarding implementing a trap, state, I couldn't figure out how to continue the DFA flow in the case of an error.

Comment: Seems like this works fine, except that once an "invalid" area is hit, I simply return instead of going into a trap state; how do I change that? Also, the language L this DFA is for (web addresses) seems to also need to work for stackoverflow.com too (no www. in this case). How would that be approached?